# Jquery- enable/disable form submit

Tags: jquery

I use the sub class to perform on click the submit of the parent form.
I would try to enable / disable the button dinamically.
I tried in this way, but even if I remove dinamically the sub class action submit remains active

HTML

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
   <div id="btn_src" class="bttn sub">CLICK ME</div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.bttn {
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   text-align: center;
}

.sub {
   background: red;
}

.disabled {
   background: grey;
}
```

JS

```
$('.bttn.sub').on('click', function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  $(form).submit();
});

var disab_btn = function() {
  $('#btn_src').removeClass('sub').addClass('disabled');
  alert($('#btn_src').attr('class'));
}

var enab_btn = function() {
  $('#btn_src').removeClass('disabled').addClass('sub');
  alert($('#btn_src').attr('class'));
}

disab_btn();
```

Then I tried removing the sub class from html, but in this case the submit action is always disabled.

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <div id="btn_src" class="bttn">CLICK ME</div>
</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fj2dqm3L/1/)

how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Disable dynamically based on what event? What condition? And why are you adding/removing classes, instead of setting/unsetting the `disabled` property?

Comment: you don't call function `disab_btn` at all!

Comment: try "$('form').on('click','.bttn.sub',function() { ..."

Comment: @DavidThomas - is not important with that event disable. the problem is that I disable btn with disab_btn the submit remains active

Comment: That's your problem, certainly, but I was meaning to ask about the context of your problem (which is why I specifically asked "*dynamically based on what event*"). Using classes to indicate enabled/disabled states is fine, but I do think using the actual `disabled` property makes more sense; but that's your call and dictated by your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.bttn.sub').on('click', function() {
  var btn = $(this),
    form = btn.closest('form');
  if (!btn.hasClass('disabled')) {//<-- added this line
    form.submit();
  }
});

var disab_btn = function() {
  $('#btn_src').removeClass('sub').addClass('disabled');
  alert($('#btn_src').attr('class'));
}

var enab_btn = function() {
  $('#btn_src').removeClass('disabled').addClass('sub');
  alert($('#btn_src').attr('class'));
}

disab_btn();
```

```css
.bttn {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.sub {
  background: red;
}
.disabled {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
  <div id="btn_src" class="bttn sub">CLICK ME</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fj2dqm3L/10/)

Wrap the code inside document ready if not already done.
2nd You cant use classes as selector like you tried. Select the form, then give action, classes to look for, and a function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('form').on('click','.bttn.sub',function() {
    alert("Clicked");
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $(form).submit();
});

var disab_btn = function() {
    $('#btn_src').removeClass('sub').addClass('disabled');
    //alert($('#btn_src').attr('class'));
}

var enab_btn = function() {
    $('#btn_src').removeClass('disabled').addClass('sub');
    //alert($('#btn_src').attr('class'));
}

enab_btn();
});
```

As an alternativ you can simply select your button by id like this:

```
 $('#btn_src').on('click', function() {
    alert("Clicked");
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $(form).submit();
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fj2dqm3L/14/)

Comment: although i call disab_btn, submit action remains

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is when you submit your form your whole page is refreshed then everything starts from the beginning. So you have to try Ajax to post your data to avoid refreshing whole page.

Comment: although i call disab_btn, submit action remains

Comment: unfortunately remains active even if I call disab_btn()

Comment: the issue is when you submit your form the whole page is refreshed then every thing is reset. you have to post the form by ajax